# iptablesでポートをACCEPTしたが、netstatなどで使用しているプロセスが確認できない

Tags: linux, centos, iptables

#### 前提・実現したいこと

redisサーバでconnectionエラーが出るのを改善しようとしています。

聞きたいことが二つあります。

- 接続先のポートを開けようとiptablesに設定を書いたが、netstat -anやtelnetで確認できない。
  　selinuxはdisabledにしていますが、それ以外に何か原因になりそうなものがあるのでしょうか。

  ```
  [hoge@fuga ~]# iptables -L
  Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
  target     prot opt source               destination
  ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:12726

  Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
  target     prot opt source               destination

  Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
  target     prot opt source               destination
  [hoge@fuga ~]# netstat -an | grep 12726
  [hoge@fuga ~]#
  ```
- 隣接する番号のポートが空いているので、そちらに向き先を変えるようにすればいいのかなと考えています。
  　気軽に向き先を変えてしまって大丈夫なものなのでしょうか。

centos6.5の環境になります。

ひょっとしたらサービスの仕様によるものなのかもしれませんが、
インフラ屋初めて日が浅いので、触り方の心構え(?)的なものがわからなくて、、

何かアドバイスをいただければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 12726 番ポートを listen しているプロセスが起動していないのではないでしょうか？

Comment: @metropolis それでした。その辺理解できていませんでした。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/93189

Answer (score 1):

@metropolis氏のコメントにより、この質問は解決したようです。

本件は、質問者の方が「ポートを許可する設定にしたのに、それを利用しているプロセスがnetstatなどで確認できないため、実際に許可出来ていないのではないか」と考えたため質問が行われたようです。

しかし、実際にはそもそもプロセスが起動しておらず、それが原因でした。

Comment: この回答は次のメタ質問を参考にコミュニティWikiとして投稿したものです。 [コメントで解決済みとなった質問の事後処理 - スタック・オーバーフローMeta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1812/%e3%82%b3%e3%83%a1%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88%e3%81%a7%e8%a7%a3%e6%b1%ba%e6%b8%88%e3%81%bf%e3%81%a8%e3%81%aa%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f%e3%81%ae%e4%ba%8b%e5%be%8c%e5%87%a6%e7%90%86)